# Access any element in a list that has a 4 in it and add 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If I have the list

```
a = [1, 7, 21,19, 8, 14, 104]
```

I want to add 1 to any element that contains the number 4. SO the output would be

```
a = [1,8, 21,19, 8, 15, 105]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a [conditional expression](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056846.html) and comprehension it is easy:

```
>>> a = [1, 7, 21,19, 8, 14, 104]
>>> [e+1 if '4' in str(e) else e for e in a]
[1, 7, 21, 19, 8, 15, 105]
```

Explanation:

1. `[e for e in a]` loops over your list element by element and produces a new list based on that;
2. [str()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) turns the integer into a string so you can test if `'4'` is in the number;
3. The Python keyword `in` tests to see if `'4'` is in the string;
4. Either add `+1` or not based on that conditional test.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
import random

arr = []

for i in range(5):
    arr.append(random.randint(1, 5))

print(arr)
```